# discord bot, how to Command response time extension

Tags: discord.js

I made a timer code.
But the slash command is valid until 15 minutes
The timer only operates for up to 15 minutes. What are some ways to stay longer?

Comment: You could use a message command instead

Answer (score 1):

There is no posibility to response slash command after 15 minutes. What you can do is

```js
interaction.reply({content:'Example'})
setTimeout(()=>{
interaction.channel.send(MessageYouWantToSend)
},time)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But it didn't work, so I used 'messagecreate' to solve the problem